# Unable to create new laravel web - "Laravel new <blog>" command isn't working

Tags: php, laravel, curl

Whenever I run `Laravel new blog`, I get this error

```
"cURL error 18: transfer closed with 148 bytes remaining to read (see http:/ /curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"
```

I googled it but didn't get much help

Comment: Have you ever successfully installed a laravel application on this machine? Do you know that Laravel is installed properly? Do you have composer installed? Brew? Need to know a little more about your setup before any help can be offered.

Comment: Yeah I had installed laravel application before (yesterday). for some reason it's not letting me install now.

composer, laravel are installed.